# Ruby on Rails, ActiveRecord callback, delayed execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Is there any callback, that will call a method after 10min the create-method was used?
Example: a picture was uploaded, create method was called, in 10 min another method should be called.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Resque https://github.com/defunkt/resque
- delayed_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

The alternatives would involve blocking your app (not an option) or looking into concurrency.

Comment: It wasn't actually what I needed because you still need to start a woker via commandline either with rake jobs:work or with a gem deamons and then by executing a file. What I need is that a method will be executed(run, called) just after a create method. So far I found nothing if it is possible to start a worker just after create method. What I need is to start a rails server, upload files and that it 10 min another method is called.