# Ruby on Rails, callback, run a method later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, delayed-job

I need somekind of a callback for a function to be caled in 5 min after the create-method.

My situation:

The user logs in in my web-page, uploads some files (create-method is invoked), in 5 min should the files be on their way to be analyzed(in 5 min it should call the method, which just take the whole folder, where the files are stored and analysis it). That is why such things like typing `rake jobs:work` or using `gem daemons` and typing `"RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start"` in the command line does not suit me.

I want to start my apllication as usual with rails s, log in, upload the files and it should work automatically that the files are analyzed.
As I understood once [the jobs started](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs) they will continue run? I do not need this. I need just some methods run in 5 min after create method.
All this stuff with `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` to qeue the jobs and `daemons` to start the workers seem too complicted for such an easy task.

So, is it possible using `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` and `gem daemons` to start my application with rails s and everythings will be done automatically in background without me stopping an application and typing things in the commanline to run the delayed jobs?
Or is it possible to do without all thise complicated stuff?

I have already asked about delayed_jobs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448859/ruby-on-rails-delayed-job) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444568/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-callback-delayed-execution).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a post where it is described [how to set up scheduling with delayedjob](http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/rails-tips-using-delayedjob-to-schedule.html)
*Update 2015-07-06:* link's broken and I can't find a cached version - see update below

If you can, I recommend looking into [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) which is a great message queue and even has built in scheduling. It does use redis though, so unless you already have redis deployed it will be a tiny bit of work.

**Update**
[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/kares/1024726) with a simple solution to scheduled and recurring jobs with delayedjob

Comment: It seems that I need to use only Delayed::Job.enqueue(MeetingReminderJob.new(user), :run_at => time_run) because I do not have postpones/remind-changes and all stuff there